# Omitting chapter numbers in section headers using memoir

Tags: numbering, memoir, chapters

I'm trying to find a way to remove the chapter number from the section headers when using `memoir`. Right now I'm using parts, but no chapters and zeroes appear in front of all section numbers. I tried reseting the chapter command like that:

```
\renewcommand\thesection{\arabic{section}}
```

or like that

```
\renewcommand\thesubsection{\arabic{section}.\arabic{subsection}}
```

and it didn't work as I expected. They both removed the chapter number, but also removed the subsection numbers. I'm sure there is a more clever way to do it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the `\counterwithout` command:

```
\counterwithout{section}{chapter}
```

See §18.8 of the `memoir` manual.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was actually in the `memoir` default section numbering depth. It was set to 1 and I needed it to be 3. Thanks for the advice, though. This is a better way to do it :)

Comment: @AleksandarSavkov: In memoir you can use the section name rather than having to remember numbers: `\setsecnumdepth{subsubsection}`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use the option `article` and `\chapter` as the sectioning heading. An MWE:

```
\documentclass[article,a4paper]{memoir}

\begin{document}

\part{Test}

\chapter{Old Test}

\part{Next Test}

\chapter{New test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Although this works, there's something perverse about `memoir`'s implementation of `article`.

Comment: @AlanMunn Maybe, but I have several hundred documents based on memoir's `article` (memos, legal opinions,bylaws, article of associations, protocols and agreement). Of course, using `\chapter` when you need a `\section` breach the logic of TeX, but a `section` is not the same in my language as in English so it doesn't matter.