# Section numbering without numbers in memoir class

Tags: memoir

How to make section numbering at preface page in memoir class?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside]{memoir}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\paragraph*{Preface}
\section{Section uncounter}
\lipsum[1]
\mainmatter
\chapter{Test Chapter}
\lipsum[1]
\section{Test Section}
\lipsum[1]
\subsection{Test Subsection}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: (1) Welcome, (2) please see in the manual what the consequences of the `\frontmatter` command is. In side the front matter section numbers are switched off.

Comment: Have you had a look in the manual? Maybe related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/62093 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3327.

Comment: @daleif Do you want to write up a short answer?

Comment: @Johannes_B added

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing here is the intended consequence of using `\frontmatter`, it disables section numbering and switches to roman numbering.

If that is not what you want, please be a bit more specific.

Note that, generally, the material added within the frontmatter is often of a summary nature, often acknowledgements are added here. If there is introductory material that is important for the rest of the document (say a thesis), then that should be added to the mainmatter, and not be placed within the frontmatter